# How Can I Use A Google Script to Keep Revision History in Google Drive for Files Edited After A Certain Date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to create a Google Script that would access my Google Drive and access all of the files modified after a certain date (for example, all files modified in the past 30 days), and set all of the revisions to be kept forever. Essentially, the goal of this is to keep revision history forever in Google Drive, but since doing it to every file every time would be both redundant and a waste of resources, it's something that I'd plan on running once every 15 or 30 days.

I cannot find anything like this on the web, so I thought to best ask the StackExchange community.

Comment: Go to [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) which is the App Script for Drive API, learn the operations and write your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does as I described, but (as with all Google Scripts) will only run for 6 minutes (or 30 if you're in EAP, currently).

```
function setRevisionPermanent() {

  var rateLimit = 200; 

  var today = new Date();  

  var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() - 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
  var oneMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  
  var startTime = oneMonth.toISOString();

  var search = '(trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "' + startTime + '")';
  var files  = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();    
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var fileId = file.getId();

    try {

      var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId).items;     

      for (var i = 0 ; i < revisions.length ; i ++) {         
        var rclone = revisions[i];
        rclone.pinned = i < revisions.length - rateLimit ? false : true;
        var request = Drive.Revisions.update(rclone, fileId, revisions[i].id);   

      }

    } catch (e) {

      Logger.log(e.message);

    }

  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to see this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions) to help you start.

To list a file's revision, you will be needing the [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list) method.

Here is a [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list#examples) .js code:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a list of revisions.
 *
 * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to retrieve revisions for.
 * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function retrieveRevisions(fileId, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.drive.revisions.list({
    'fileId': fileId
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

Other methods is also available:

- [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/delete)
- [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get)
- [patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/patch)
- [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/update)

Just play with this methods to form the function you needed.